# FCKEditor Hide frmupload.html

Tags: security, asp-classic, fckeditor

I have a huge old web app written in classic asp that uses FCKEditor.

The client are currently running a security check on their sites and have flagged that when not logged in you can directly access

> /fckeditor/editor/filemanager/browser/default/frmupload.html

You cannot actually upload as far as I can tell but you can get to the page and this is bothering them.

The site is slowly being upgraded in sections but the part in which this fckeditor is in is a long way off.

Is there anyway in the mean time to stop this page being served when not logged in?

Comment: Why don't you change the extension to.asp, then implement the existing login/access features and change the references to that site?

Comment: Maybe rename it to something impossible to guess, and insist on FTP uploads only.

Comment: I'm with @stare, it's the best option. Check some page that has the login validation and use it in the new `frmupload.asp`.

Comment: The page is part of FCKEditor and I'm not entirely sure how it uses it but will try changing ti .asp and references and see if it breaks it.

Comment: What the file does is to select a file from your own machine for upload, using Javascript.  If you click on the insert image button and then select the upload tab, frmupload.html is what you can see within that tab.  FCKeditor was renamed CKEditor quite a while ago so you're using an old version which might have security issues

Comment: @John this site is old as the hills so definitely an old version. Do you know if I just rename it to .asp and add come security into it should that all be ok?

Comment: That should work, but you'll need to change every reference to it in the FCKEditor directory, a lot of which will be buried in JS functions.  Do you have an editor with a global search and replace feature?  If you don't need to use FCKeditor it to upload stuff then I suppose you could just replace the file with a blank html page

Answer (score 1):

Can you make changes in IIS configuration?

If Yes, start handle HTML page as ASP page.

In IIS 7.5 will be looks like:

[image]

After that just add security validation code into your page (frmupload.html).

*P.S. I am also stick with old FCKEditor on ASP code, but i am moving it to old FCKEditor powered on ASP.NET :)

I am not planning to use CKEditor, because File browser & File upload are critical for me and i don't wont spend money buying these modules.*

Comment: FCKeditor is fine as long as you sanitize all inputs and hide the editor page from public using member login.